# How to compare a textview outside of the table to a textview in a table row?

Tags: android

```
   public void filter(TableLayout tl, String regex) {
       TableRow tr;
       TextView tv;
       Pattern p;
       Matcher m;

       p = Pattern.compile(regex);
       int n = tl.getChildCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
           tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
           m = p.matcher(tv.getText());
           if (m.find()) {
               tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } else {
               tr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
```

I have tried to do filter for a tablelayout on aftertextchanged . The value of the text is passed into filter method perfectly but    `tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);` gives me android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView. As most other forums show that there is an id for the textview as it is hardcoded , I did not manage to find one that solves the error of textview that is put in dynamically. Below is an example of what I add to the table layout which works peerfectly fine.

```
public void addData(ArrayList<Transactions> Transactions) {

        tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        addHeader();
        int j = 1;
        for (Iterator i = Transactions.iterator(); i.hasNext(); j++) {
            Transactions p = (Transactions) i.next();

            if (p.getAdminNo().equals(adminNo)) {

                /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
                tr = new TableRow(this);

                /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
                label = new TextView(this);
                label.setText(String.valueOf(j));
                label.setId(p.getId());

                acd = String.valueOf(p.getId());
                label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
                //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
                Ll.addView(label, params);
                tr.addView((View) Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.
```

This is my xml file. When i put a value into my edittext, it will trigger filter method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:textColor="#00f0ff"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/maintable" >
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post in your xml files so we would know whats really going on, but since its a cast exception then its likely that the views are not returned in the order youre expecting. Kindly post the xml files

Comment: I have added accordingly . Could you please take a look again? If needed, I would post other codes you need to help me out . Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its throwing a cast exception is because the first item you are adding to the table view is the linearlayout

```
Ll.addView(label, params); //adding textview to linearlayout
tr.addView((View) Ll); // Adding linearlayout to tablerow.
```

Since its just an item you want to add to the tablerow, I dont think you need the linearlayout. What you can do is this:

```
public void addData(ArrayList<Transactions> Transactions) {

    tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    addHeader();
    int j = 1;
    for (Iterator i = Transactions.iterator(); i.hasNext(); j++) {
        Transactions p = (Transactions) i.next();

        if (p.getAdminNo().equals(adminNo)) {

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(String.valueOf(j));
            label.setId(p.getId());

            acd = String.valueOf(p.getId());
            label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            tr.addView((label); // Adding textView to tablerow.
    }
}
```

But if you must add the linearlayout, you should get back the textview by doing this

```
public void filter(TableLayout tl, String regex) {
   TableRow tr;
   TextView tv;
   Pattern p;
   Matcher m;

   p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   int n = tl.getChildCount();
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
       LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tr.getChildAt(0);
       tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
       m = p.matcher(tv.getText());
       if (m.find()) {
           tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       } else {
           tr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
```

This should work. Hopefully it helps, goodluck

Comment: Is it possible to link you to another question as after the filter I realised that the header of the table would be gone and adding the method would put the header below the data retrieved

Comment: Okay no problems, link me up and I'll try to answer it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518233/header-shows-only-at-the-end-of-the-table-layout-in-android

Comment: I would like to ask how do i do it if I have a few textviews to compare